# How to fix ionic app that is working slow after updating xcode to 8.3 and using IOS version 10.3?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, xcode8

i have updated my xcode to 8.3 , mac OS sierra 10.12.5 , IOS 10.3 on device i am tesing an app , My ionic app is working very slow after this and its perfectly working fine with IOS versions 9.3 and above , i am not getting what is the issue with my ionic app .

MY xcode simulator is also not working after selecting the devices having IOS version 10.3, i am getting the below mentioned error in xcode :

DDWebKitOperation:  0x6100000ea080:  container  WebFrame: 0x618000009260 has been modified too many times, aborting